# itertools count with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-itertools

I want to pass the `itertools.count` element as a list index, but it results in this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not itertools.count

Trying `int(counter)` does not work either, resulting in

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'itertools.count'

```
from itertools import count

index = count()
l = [5,6,7,8,9,0]

while True:
    print(l[int(index)])
```

How can I pass the count as the list index?

Comment: what you exactly you want to do?

Comment: print the elements of the list

Comment: @inyrface simply use `print(l)` you do not need `count` for this

Comment: I tried ```index.__str__`` but it gives the whole item e.g. count(0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next` to get the next element from the counter.

```py
from itertools import count

index = count()
l = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

while True:
    print(l[next(index)])
```

But the way your loop is currently structured, this will eventually result in an `IndexError` when the counter has reached 6, since your list only has 6 elements.

The output will look like this:

```
5
6
7
8
9
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(l[next(index)])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you just want to print the elements of the list, you can do this with Python much easier like this:

```py
for element in l:
    print(element)
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to solve if you would give a direct example of what you are trying to achieve. Even if it's just the input and expected output.

Comment: essentially the problem is to use ```itertools.count``` as an index/integer

Comment: so I still have to define ```i```?